# How to insert a data before another one in Linked list?

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm trying to insert data before another data in a linked list but when I insert data after specific data . Instead of inserted before it. It's going to insert after that specific data. Here is my code, need correction, and  Thanks in advance.

```java
public void InsertBefore(int key, int element) {

    Node current = head;
    Node prev = null;

    if (head != null) {

        while (current != null) {

            if (current.equals(key)) {

                Node n = new Node(element);
                n.next = current;

                if (prev != null) {
                    prev.next = n;
                }
                return;
            }

            prev = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a first step you should fix the indentation.

Comment: A [mre] should be able to be copy/pasted into an ide and run. Therefore, in Java it must include any import statements, the class, and the main() method. It should be made so that it demonstrates the problem while still being easily readable.

Comment: The definition of Node is important to the understanding of this code.

Comment: You may need to special-case what happens if 1) you have to insert an element as the first element, or 2) what happens if you cannot find the element to insert before.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use current.equals() to check equality of two elements in the Node class. Do

`Node current = head;
Node prev = null;

```
               if (head != null) 
               {
                  while (current != null) 
                 {
                      if(current.value.equals(key))
                      {
                          Node n = new Node(element);
                          n.next = current;
        
                              if (prev != null)
                              {
                              prev.next = n;
                      }
                         return;
                }
   
                    prev = current;
                    current = current.next;
                  }
             }
            }
         }`
```

Supposing your Node class is as below and the 'key' is also a String

` static class Node{
String value;
Node next;

```
    Node(String value){
        this.value = value;
        this.next = null;
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have implemented the Node.equals() correctly or try this

```
 public static void InsertBefore(int key, int element) {

    Node current = head;
    Node prev = null;

    if (head != null) {
        while (current != null) {
            if (current.element == key) {
                Node n = new Node(element);
                n.next = current;

                if (prev != null) {
                    prev.next = n;
                } else {
                    head = n;
                }
                return;
            }

            prev = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
    }

}
```